# Finish the sequence

Tags: lateral-thinking

1 $\to$ 4 $\to$ 6
2 $\to$ 3 $\to$ 7
19 $\to$ 16 $\to$ 11
8 $\to$ 14 $\to$ 12
15 $\to$ 17 $\to$ 19
18 $\to$ 13 $\to$ __

Comment: Logical deduction AND lateral thinking?

Comment: I think lateral thinking is a more apt tag than logical thinking so removed it.

Comment: Removing one tag is a kind of a hint.

Comment: The last number in consecutive sequences have a difference of 1. So, that way it should be 20.

Comment: It's a time to give a hint. Letters, hours of a day, something else?

Answer (score 3):

Possible guess:

> It was an *even number*: **10**.
>  Also possibly one of the two 19 was actually 9.
>  Since the number used was: 1,2,3,4,?,6,7,8,?,?,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
>  Pattern:
>
> ```
> O E E
> E O O
> O E O
> E E E
> O O O
> E O ?
> ```

Comment: It is two 19's and not a 9.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of each row-
11
12
36
34
51
Since sum of first two rows show increment of 1 and sum of next two rows show decrement of 2 and sum of fifth row is 51 therefore there should be increment of 3 between row 5 and 6. So the answer is 23 which gives 54 as sum of last row.

Answer (score -3):

> Answer is 23. You have to to find the patter and let post it wether you have find something new. I am typing all this because my answer has to be more than 30 character long.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Can you please explain how you obtained that answer? It's not clear in the current state of your answer. Happy puzzling  :)